# C++ mark arithmetic hard-coded fraction as constexpr in a one-liner

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have a simple function that checks if a value is bigger than one third:

```
bool check(float x) {
   return x > 1.f/3;
}
```

Based on what I've read, the compilers will probably calculate the result of 1.f/3 at compile time to improve performance, but is not required to. To force him doing that, it's recommended to use:

```
bool check(float x) {
   constexpr float one_third = 1.f/3;
   return x > one_third;
}
```

My question is whether there is a way to do this as a one-liner, without having to define a separate expression. Something like:

```
bool check(float x) {
   return x > (constexpr float(1.f/3));
}
```

I could not find any way to do it and wanted to ask for confirmation. I found if-constexpr, but that requires both sides of the if to be constexpr, not just an internal subset of it. Lambda-constexpr or consteval could maybe work as oneliners?

Comment: "it's recommended to use" says who? I expect exactly same oppotunities for the compiler in either case

Comment: The compiler has all information it needs to know what `1.f/3` is. The `constexpr` does not add something useful. For the reader maybe, but not for the compiler

Comment: You can use a lambda and immediately invoke it as in `return [x]()constexpr{return x>float(1.f/3);}(); `

Comment: Even more that in this specific case, even the non-optimized compiler will produce the same code. https://godbolt.org/z/fh4d1E9rh 
One could make an argument for certain cases where non-optimized builds will have different code when using constexpr variables vs not doing so (mainly when the variable is initialized from a constexpr-function), but here, it the output is literally the same under all circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`consteval` lambda (C++20) might be used:

```
bool check(float x) {
   return x > []() consteval { return 1.f/3; }();
}
```

but I prefer the `static constexpr` variant for readability

```
bool check(float x) {
   static constexpr float one_third = 1.f/3;
   return x > one_third;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: If you want to do it in one line / expression, your first version is totally fine.

Your question is based on the false premise that you would need to inform the compiler that `1.f/3` is a compile time constant. Though, the compiler knows that, you don't need to add a `constexpr`. Whoever recommended you to modify the initial version of the function didn't know what they were talking about. Thats the only explanation I can come up with. The `constexpr` does not add something useful. It does not open up opportunities for optimization that were not present in the original code. Also splitting it up into two lines does not affect optimizations.

If you ask gcc to optimize the codes it will produce identical output:

```
bool check1(float x) {
   return x > 1.f/3;
}

bool check2(float x) {
   constexpr float one_third = 1.f/3;
   return x > one_third;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/5K681j4bn):

```
check1(float):
        comiss  xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        seta    al
        ret
check2(float):
        comiss  xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        seta    al
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1051372203
```

---

`constexpr if` is for compile time conditions, but `x > 1.f/3;` can only be evaluated at runtime.

---

It would be useful to declare `1.f/3` as `constexpr` when you want to use it in a context that requires a constant expression, for example:

```
 constexpr float x = 1.f/3;
 foobar<x>();               // use x as template argument
```

But thats not the case in the context of your function.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting with a wrong premise.

All three major compilers (Clang, GCC, MSVC) generate **worse** assembly with `constexpr` variable when optimizations are disabled, and the same assembly when optimizations are enabled.

Here's Clang, for example: https://godbolt.org/z/qjvherx4v

Don't waste time worrying about microoptimizations on non-existent weird compilers.

Comment: The non-optimized codegen for both cases is the same if "static constexpr" is used. There is a difference between the two in practice, though don't ask me why exactly.

Answer (score -2):

> whether there is a way to **do this as a one-liner**,

Yes, you can use a lambda and immediately invoke it:

```
bool constexpr check(float x) 
{
   return [x]()constexpr{return x>float(1.f/3);}(); 
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EEWPhvdKc)

Comment: I don't see what this achieves. `constexpr` functions/lambdas can run at runtime. When optimizations are disabled, compilers will usually execute them at runtime, unless you use the result in constexpr context (which you do in your link, by assigning it to a constexpr variable). Making `check()` constexpr is enough, adding a lambda doesn't do anything here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This answers the question explicitly asked by OP *"whether there is a way to do this as a one-liner,  without having to define a separate expression"*

Comment: But it doesn't? Your code is equivalent to just `bool constexpr check(float x) {return x > 1.f/3;}`, the lambda doesn't do anything. It doesn't force the division to run at compile-time, unlike a constexpr variable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat By using the lambda, OP can add more logic into lambda's body.

Comment: It's the same thing as adding it directly to `check`'s body.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But that will not be one-liner(statement)

Comment: The function body is one big statement, just like a lambda body. But either way, `constexpr` doesn't force the division to happen at compile-time unless the function result is used at compile-time.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I am aware that a function body itself is a one big statement. But that was not the question. The question was to reduce the code inside it into one-liner which I did.

Comment: A constexpr lambda is not equivalent to a constexpr variable, it doesn't force compile-time evaluation. E.g. https://godbolt.org/z/vsoW4aEo6

Comment: `constexpr float one_third = 1.f/3; return x > one_third;` is also one line

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai No, it is not one liner. One liner means one-statement.

Comment: I thought there was agreement that the body of the funciton is one big statement and that "the question was to reduce the code inside it into one-liner"  which you did. Now its one statement again. Ok